# Data is not posting in MVC Controller for select2 List Box Mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Multi-Select text box in my view..
Below is my code

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Multiple", "Home",  new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
<div class="col-md-2  col-xs-2">Associated Segment</div>
    <div class="col-md-4  col-xs-4">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SegmentList, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.List, "Value", "Text", Model.SegmentList.AsEnumerable()), new { @class = "form-control tokenizationSelect2", @multiple = "multiple" })
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12  col-xs-12">
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding:1%;">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="btnSaveProbDiagnosis" type="submit" name="">save</button>
        </div>
    </div>

}
<link href="~/scripts/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/select2.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/select2.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".tokenizationSelect2").select2({
            placeholder: "Your favourite car", //placeholder
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: ['/', ',', ';', " "]
        });
    })
</script>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Multiple(ViewModal viewmoddal)
        {                
            return View();
        }
```

Modal:

```
public class ViewModal
    {
       public int QuestionId { get; set; }
       public string question { get; set; }
       public string type { get; set; }
       public List<SegmentList> SegmentList { get; set; }
       public List<Answer> option { get; set; }

    }
```

Its perfectly binding data in the UI. But when I am posting the data to controller
data not going to controller.

someone please help me in this...

Comment: can you post your controller action code ?

Comment: Have added my Contoller

Comment: multiple select expects an array of value types to bind and post back. please make sure your model have those values.

Comment: @HazarathChillara i have added my model. Pls let me know what changes i have to do in my modal..

Comment: check my answer. you need to define array of integers to define segmentids and bind those to list in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define array of integers to bind to multi select and these will be posted to controller actions. for.e.g in your case define your model like this.

```
public class ViewModal
{
  public int[] SelectedSegments { get; set; }
  public List<Segment> SegmentList { get; set; }
}
```

and in view

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedSegments, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.List, "Value", "Text", Model.SegmentList.AsEnumerable()), new { @class = "form-control tokenizationSelect2", @multiple = "multiple" })
```